# 4T RAID 0 Partitioning issue

Tags: bios, raid, uefi, mbr, gpt

I am building a new workstation

```
1.2T 10K SAS X 4 for Win 7 Pro SP1 x64
```

I must use RAID 0 for this workstation. What I would like to have is

```
C = 500G
D = rest of spaces
```

So BOIS based system with MBR wont suport such amount size of drive due to the limitation. UEFI based system with GPT also have issues when I trying to partition the 4T RAID 0. I partitioned C as 500G then they rest of spaces automatically became 2 parts 1.5T and 2.5 T.

Is there a way that I can configure 4T RAID 0 as I maintained above?

Comment: For intel and other raid systems you can create 2 arrays. arrays that would utalise all 4 disk items without using all the space for it. A raid array can be a little like partitioning. To test that theory with your specific raid system, create an array using all of the disks, but set the size of that array smaller than the whole, like your 500G. Then see if you can create a second array.  Once created a person could MBR the boot one for legasy boot capability , and GPT the other array for huge sizes. Most of the raid stuff will hande this the same, but you did not mention the hardware/software

Comment: Try keeping UEFI turned off and just let windows installer switch to GPT automatically.  You do not need to use UEFI to use GPT.  It should let you carve the disk up like you described in manual partitioning mode in the installer.

Comment: I did that and I got an error saying " windows cannot be installed to this disk. this computer's hardware may not support booting to disk. ensure that the disk controller is enabled in the BIOS menu" I dont see any options in BOIS or UEFI has such functions.....

Comment: @AdamStrohl, actually, no... Windows only supports GPT with UEFI.

Comment: Create the raid array, boot the windows install disc in uefi mode, and install should work just fine.